# Action listener не срабатывает

Tags: java, gui, checkbox

При нажатии на чекбокс ничего не происходит до тех пор, пока не раскрыть выпадающий список.

Но у меня возник ещё один вопрос: как скрывать **licence_password** и **password** , когда **checkbox** не выбран, но показывать, когда он выбран?

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Assembly assembly = new Assembly();
        Server server = new Server();
        JFrame Mainframe = new JFrame();
        JPanel Mainpanel = new JPanel();

        Mainframe.setSize(1050, 700);
        Mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Mainframe.add(Mainpanel);
        Mainframe.setTitle("none");
        JCheckBox licence = new JCheckBox("Лицензия");
        licence.setBounds(450, 630, 150, 30);
        Mainpanel.add(licence);
        licence.setSelected(false);
        licence.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                if (licence.isSelected()) {
                    JLabel licence_password = new JLabel("Пароль");
                    licence_password.setBounds(200, 560, 100,100 );
                    Mainpanel.add(licence_password);

                    JTextField password = new JTextField(20);
                    password.setBounds(180, 620, 150, 20);
                    Mainpanel.add(password);



                    }
                }
            });
        JLabel version = new JLabel("Версия:");
        version.setBounds(20,560,150,20);
        Mainpanel.add(version);
        String[] items = {
            "1.12.2",
            "1.12.2 Forge",
            "1.12.2 Forge+Optifine"
        };
        JComboBox version_ComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
        version_ComboBox.setBounds(70,560,150,20);
        Mainpanel.add(version_ComboBox);

        Mainframe.setVisible(true);
             }
        }
```

P.S
Проблему с выпадающим списком решил,

```
JCheckBox licence = new JCheckBox("Лицензия");
        licence.setBounds(450, 630, 150, 30);
        Mainpanel.add(licence);
        licence.setSelected(false);
        licence.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel licence_password = new JLabel("Пароль");
                JTextField password = new JTextField(20);
                licence_password.setBounds(200, 560, 100, 100);
                Mainpanel.add(licence_password);
                licence_password.setVisible(false);

                password.setBounds(180, 620, 150, 20);
                Mainpanel.add(password);
                password.setVisible(false);

                if (licence.isSelected()) {

                    licence_password.setVisible(true);
                    password.setVisible(true);
                    
                 } 

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код, который должен создать метку и поле ввода пароля, вынесите из листенера, а оставьте там только действия по скрытию/открытию этих элементов:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Assembly assembly = new Assembly();
        Server server = new Server();
        JFrame Mainframe = new JFrame();
        JPanel Mainpanel = new JPanel();

        Mainframe.setSize(1050, 700);
        Mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Mainframe.add(Mainpanel);
        Mainframe.setTitle("none");
        JCheckBox licence = new JCheckBox("Лицензия");
        licence.setBounds(450, 630, 150, 30);
        Mainpanel.add(licence);
        licence.setSelected(false);

        JLabel version = new JLabel("Версия:");
        version.setBounds(20,560,150,20);
        Mainpanel.add(version);
        String[] items = {
                "1.12.2",
                "1.12.2 Forge",
                "1.12.2 Forge+Optifine"
        };
        JComboBox version_ComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
        version_ComboBox.setBounds(70,560,150,20);
        Mainpanel.add(version_ComboBox);

        JLabel licence_password = new JLabel("Пароль");
        JTextField password = new JTextField(20);
        licence_password.setBounds(200, 560, 100, 100);
        Mainpanel.add(licence_password);
        licence_password.setVisible(false);

        password.setBounds(180, 620, 150, 20);
        Mainpanel.add(password);
        password.setVisible(false);

        if (licence.isSelected()) {

            licence_password.setVisible(true);
            password.setVisible(true);

        }
        licence.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                licence_password.setVisible(licence.isSelected());
                password.setVisible(licence.isSelected());
            }
        });

        Mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему `if (licence.isSelected())` работает только с **true**? Например, если мне при выделенном чекбоксе нужно скрыть **Ник** и написать **Логин**, то я не могу просто написать `name.isSelected(false);` .

Comment: Точнее не `name.isSelected(false);`  а `name.setVisible(false);`

Comment: Оказалось всё намного интереснее: if тут вообще не работает.